# Convert byte to binary, append output to string, convert to double, print output...losing bits on output

Tags: c, syntax

So, I am having trouble with some code.

I want this function to take in a byte array(testing with single byte for now), convert the byte into binary and then append it to a "1." to use in a calculation.

ex:

ouput: 01110000 ----> 1.01110000

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

double calcByteValue(uint8_t data[], int size);

int main() {
   uint8_t test[10];
   test[0] = 0x0e;

   double d = calcByteValue(test, 8);
   return 0;
}

double calcByteValue(uint8_t data[], int size) {
    int i;
    uint8_t bits[21];
    char binary[100];
    char str[100] = "1.";

    for (i = 0;i < size;i++) {                    
            bits[i] = (data[0] >> i) & 1;
            if (bits[i] == 0) {
                binary[i] = '0';
                printf("0(%d)\n", i);
            } else {
                binary[i] = '1';
                printf("1(%d)\n", i);
            }
    }

    strcat(str, binary);
    float d = atof(str);
    printf("%f\n", d);
    return 0;
    //return pow(-1, bits[0]) * pow(2, (128-127)) * atof(str));
}
```

Here is my output, for some reason it is going through the whole loop just fine, but only printing 6 of the original bits, knocking off the last couple ones.  What am I doing wrong???

```
0(0)
1(1)
1(2)
1(3)
0(4)
0(5)
0(6)
0(7)
1.011100
```

Comment: I think that was just a typo when I was typing the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
strcat(str, binary);
```

You never null terminated the `binary` array. You have to to use it as a string.

```
 char binary[100];
```

`binary` is defined at block scope, and block scope automatic objects that are not explicitly initialized have an indeterminate value.

Here is how to null terminate the array:

```
binary[size] = '\0';
```

Second:

you are inserting the bits values in the reverse order. Put `(data[0] >> 7) & 1` for `binary[0]`, `(data[0] >> 6) & 1` for `binary[1]` and so on.

Also `printf` with `%f` conversion specification prints 6 digits after the decimal point. If you want more digits (e.g., 16), you can specify the precision like this: `printf("%.16f\n", d);`

You are also using the type `float` for object `d`, if you find you don't have enough precision with `float`, you can use type `double`.

Comment: Alternatively you could declare char binary[100] = {}

Comment: @Bingo you certainly mean `{0}`, as `{}` is a *gcc-ism*. This would initialize all array elements to `0` where only one element is required to be `0`.

Comment: Wow, I tried %.8f and it worked.  Thanks!  I'm sure I can easily find a way to shift through it without having to write out each location of the binary array.  Thanks again. Edit: got it working perfectly.  Just added:

    for (i = 0,j = 7,i<size;i++,j--)

Comment: I still can't shake the idea from my head that the result you have is not what you wanted. For one thing, this is still just an approximation of the actual value...

Comment: @ouah no I mean {}. If your doing funny things with raw strings, then you often come across errors where you forget trailing nulls. They don't happen if the whole buffer is zero.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a string to a float like that, you're always going to lose some precision. You can hardly ever express a decimal number as a float precisely. 1.0111000 is a decimal number, not a binary one.

Comment: Really, it's only 8 bits and two small numbers?  ..How should I go about this?

Comment: According to `atof` it's not 8 bits, it's a decimal number which is slightly larger than 1. Why do you need a float actually? I don't know what you want to achieve with converting a byte value to a string and then to a floating point number.